# Pcap filter for capturing only rx packets of a particular interface

Tags: pcap, libpcap

Trying to capture all rx packets of particular interface(eth0). Need to compile a filter for the same. What should be the filter string?

Comment: What libpcap version are you using?

Comment: @pchaigno I'm using "libpcap-1.5.3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select the direction in the filter, but you can do it at the libpcap level, with the function [`pcap_setdirection`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_setdirection), declared as:

```c
int pcap_setdirection(pcap_t *p, pcap_direction_t d);

typedef enum {
   PCAP_D_INOUT = 0, # To capture both RX and TX, default.
   PCAP_D_IN,        # To capture RX only.
   PCAP_D_OUT        # To capture TX only.
} pcap_direction_t;
```